# Why writing the directive access_log on twice actually turn off log?

Tags: nginx, nginx-config

The following nginx.conf can show the peoblem

```
server {
    listen 80;  
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log combined;
    access_log on;
    ...
    location / {
      access_log on;  # write it the second time actually turn off the log!
      ...
    }
    ...
 }
```

So write `access_log on;` twice actually turn off the log. Why is that ? I can't help wondering is it a bug ?

Thanks

---- update ----

It turned that there is only `access_log off` directive, no `access_log on` (no idea why I got that in the first place :$) so when I wrote `access_log on` the log was wrote to a file called "on", not `/var/log/nginx/access.log` as I expected. So I thought why there is no log ?! :$

Comment: But there is [no](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_log_module.html#access_log) special value `on` for this directive. Aren't you just writing log to filename `on`?

Comment: No I check the log file and verify if I don't write access_log on; in location / I will get the log.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the expected behavior. From [NGINX blog](https://www.nginx.com/blog/sampling-requests-with-nginx-conditional-logging/):

> Access Logs Are Not Inherited
>
> Access log settings do not stack or inherit; an access_log directive in one context overrides (replaces) access logs declared in parent contexts.

So if you don't put `access_log on;` in `location / {` then you get two log files because the ones in `server` context will apply. Contrary, if you put `access_log on;` in `location / {` then the outer scope's access log configuration will not apply.

Comment: Do you mean there is indeed a file called "on" that will get log ?

Comment: Yes, of course. As I noted in the initial comment, `on` is not a special value. So you have specified filename "on".

Comment: Hi I just verified what you said it was indeed a file "on" :$